# Which msvcp100.dll/msvcr100.dll to deploy for customers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment

With my product I have deployed specific versions of msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll that also belong to a redistribution package. To be more precise, I use them from my directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC100.CRT`. I just put these dlls into the installation directory of my software. And yes, my software is compiled as x86 and with Visual Studio 2010.

Those work fine on my machine. However, I see that some customers get errors that can be solved by removing those files and manually installing the Visual Studio 2010 redistributables with the online installer from Microsoft. The errors will be of the form:

> This application has failed to start because MSVCR100.dll
> was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

I thought that msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll are in some kind unique but there seem to be different version to be out there. How should I deploy these files to my customers such that it works for all of them? If this is not possible, what would be a good way to deploy these files?

Comment: What errors do they get? The best way is to install the Redistributable Package from MS as you mention...

Comment: The exact error is "This application has failed to start because MSVCR<version number>.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Comment: And what is the version number? ;-)

Comment: 100. Sorry, I considered it would be clear based on the question

Comment: Strange... It was not clear as you wrote your comment, because your application could use library / SDK, which requires different version of the runtime than your application requires.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the issue. I have used depends.exe to check for other dependencies

Comment: Then I would check, if there are some breaking changes in updates (VS 2010 SP1), but they should not. Did you compare installed *.dll with the packed in your zip?

Comment: Yes, they have a difference of a little bit over 2,000 bytes or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS version and architecture, so its better to add the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package in your installer as prerequisite, so that the installer can check the system if its actually required or not and then install/skip it accordingly.

Comment: I see. How would you handle it if you offered a `zip` file for your software, so that I can run without the necessity to install?

Comment: Try using Inno Setup or NSIS, both of them are free to use, and have a lots of tutorial on internet.